# PhpStorm - WSL - How to correctly set the version control mapping for multiple folders inside a vendor folder?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

PhpStorm version: 2021.3.

I have checked every old questions on this site, but there is nothing what could help me. What I want achieve is set multiple git repositories in one project. Below you will find the structure:

```
Project:
- src/
- Modules/
- vendor/
   - myPackage/test1/
   - myPackage/test2/
```

I have set in "Version Control > Directory Mappings" at the first position the main `Project` directory. But after that, while I'm trying set the second VCS with the path: `Project\vendor\myPackage\test1` I receive that message:

> The directory `<Project>\vendor\myPackage\test1` is registered as a Git
> root, but no Git repositories were found there.

What am I doing wrong, or what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: *I have checked every old questions on this site* That's a bold claim, considering there are millions of questions on stackoverflow.com. How did you read them all so fast? :-) Seriously, are you looking for an IDE-specific answer, just for IntelliJ?

Comment: I mean questions ( and problems ) similar to my own.